# How to change factors to be grouped in a barplot

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I tried to do a barplot to a factorial anova dataset by using R. However, R automatically plots each bar corresponds to different columns of my dataset matrix. How can I do a barplot with each bar corresponds to different rows instead?

```
             High demand  Low demand  None
Difficult         934        739       465      
Easy              517        396       392
```

Comment: I'm not sure what format anova gives you data in, but you might try to transpose it with `t`

Comment: Oh that's exactly what I mean, so if I have a dataset called ab_group, do I need to use t(ab_group) and then do the barplot? @Frank

Comment: That's what I meant, but I'm not sure it'll work, as I don't work with bar plots much. You could try it. If it doesn't, someone else might come along with a better idea. In the meantime, it might help to add `dput(ab_group)` to the text of your question so folks have something more concrete to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of this:

```
barplot(as.matrix(ab_group),legend.text = TRUE,col=1:nrow(ab_group))
barplot(as.matrix(ab_group),legend.text = TRUE,
        beside=T,col=1:nrow(ab_group))
barplot(as.matrix(t(ab_group)),legend.text = TRUE,col=1:ncol(ab_group))
barplot(as.matrix(t(ab_group)),legend.text = TRUE,
        beside=T,col=1:ncol(ab_group))
```

The last one is here:
[image]